# Best way to pass metadata between XNA & WPF for a level editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xna, routed-events

I have a pre-existing game in XNA that I've unfortunately lost the level editor code for. Before it used to run as a separate .exe, but I've done the work to modify the game so that it can be paused to run a level editor in the game itself. I'd like to use WPF to actually do the level editing as it seems well-suited to the task, but I don't know the best way to pass information between the two systems.

My XNA game spawns a WPF Window and I've registered events with the XNA game such that when I click a Button on the WPF Window, the XNA game receives the ClickEvent and responds appropriately. This worked wonderfully for placing objects that require no initialization data other than position (things like statues), which I simply interpret in XNA directly. However, now I have objects that have more information that the user defines in the WPF editor (e.g. starting enemy health) and I'm not sure of the best way to route the information across to XNA. I'm especially trying to keep in mind that eventually, I'll want to make it so that I can click an object in the game to edit it "in-line" (or at least make it appear that way to the person using the level editor). So essentially, I'll need to be able to set the WPF control values based on information stored in XNA when the user clicks on an object in XNA.

Here's what I've thought of so far, but none of these were as straight forward as I'd like them to be and so I'm not sure that I'm going down the right path.

1. Override RoutedEventArgs to include the extra metadata that I need such that when the event is raised from WPF and picked up by XNA, all of the extra information is there already.

   - This seems to be an ok approach, but doesn't really help me at all when I want to go the other way around.
   - Also, I could be misunderstanding how this works, but it seems like I needed to add a bunch of generic EventHandler code to my XNA game that was not required for the "statue" case.
2. Override the Button class to attach the extra metadata I need and then access it via sender or RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSender

   - This seems like one of the easier approaches, but feels a bit forced. The information doesn't really belong as part of the Button.
   - I'm not sure how this will work for passing the information back from XNA to WPF.
3. Get the information via sender.Parent or RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSender.Parent, which will require casting it to the appropriate WPF UI element.

   - This seems relatively easy, but is kind of ugly. It basically means putting a bunch of regular C# style properties that get their value set when things like ComboBoxes have a change/selection event.
   - This seems easier to go the other way with than making a custom Button, but I haven't spend serious time looking at it yet.

Any help / direction would be appreciated. I'm also happy to post any relevant code snippets, but the game is quite large and the WPF implementation so far is extremely basic, so I'm not sure what would be helpful.